# Атрибут xmlns не даёт получить XElement

Tags: c#, xml

Работаю в Visual Studio 2017, проект на c#. Имеется XML файл, который пытаюсь распарсить с помощью стандартной библиотеки System.Xml.Linq. Вот текст файла

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SCL version="2007" revision="A"
 xmlns="http://www.iec.ch/61850/2003/SCL"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.iec.ch/61850/2003/SCL
C:\Data\sdps\SCL3.0\SCL.xsd">
   <!-- Содержимое элемента -->
</SCL>
```

Вот код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(args[0]);
    XElement xe = xdoc.Element("SCL");
    if (xe == null)
    {
        Exit("Отсутствует элемент \"SCL\"");
        return;
    }
    //...
}
```

Если в xml присутствует строка

```
xmlns="http://www.iec.ch/61850/2003/SCL"
```

то

```
xe == null
```

а если эту строку удалить, то 'xe' будет иметь содержимое, которое ожидается получить.

Почему так происходит и как-то можно нормально парсить xml с наличием строки "xmlns="http://www.iec.ch/61850/2003/SCL""?

Comment: Правильнее получать корневой элемент из свойства `XDocument.Root`.

Comment: @rdon, да, Вы правы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Полное имя тэга (Qualified Name, QName) состоит из двух частей - локального имени ("SCL") и пространства имен (`"http://www.iec.ch/61850/2003/SCL"`). Для того чтобы найти тэг по имени - вам нужно указать обе части.

Сделать это можно разными способами, вот некоторые:

```
xdoc.Element("{http://www.iec.ch/61850/2003/SCL}SCL");

xdoc.Element(XName.Get("SCL", "http://www.iec.ch/61850/2003/SCL"));

XNamespace NS = "http://www.iec.ch/61850/2003/SCL";
xdoc.Element(NS + "SCL");
```

Также на всякий случай напоминаю, что атрибут `xmlns` в языке XML задает так называемое *пространство имен по умолчанию*, которое автоматически применяется ко всем дочерним элементам (но не применяется к атрибутам!)

Comment: @Olejan, надо писать неймспейс полностью, включая `http://`

Comment: @Olejan, странно, у меня код из этого ответа работает нормально

Comment: @Olejan значит, где-то у вас опечатка. Возможно что в вопросе.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, благодарю за ответ - это то, что надо

Answer (score 3):

Как правильно написал @Pavel Mayorov в соседнем ответе для выбора элемента необходимо указывать помимо локального имени еще и пространство имен, но если вы не хотите его указывать или не знаете его, можно воспользоваться возможностями Linq:

```
XElement xe = xdoc.Elements().SingleOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "SCL");
Console.WriteLine(xe);
```

Т.е. перебираем все элементы (`.Elements()`) и выбираем среди них тот, у которого *локальное имя* имеет значение `"SCL"` (`.SingleOrDefault(...)`)

Comment: благодарю - этот метод сработал.