# Как сделать выборку XmlDocument.SelectNodes(), если у документа задан targetNamespace?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

В корневом элементе xml-документа заданы следующие атрибуты:

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
version="0.1" 
elementFormDefault="qualified"
```

Далее идет набор элементов без префиксов такого вида

```
<element name="Signature" type="ds:SignatureType"/>
```

Что нужно сделать чтобы XmlDocument.SelectNodes("element") возвращал не нулевое количество элементов?

Полный текст xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" version="0.1" elementFormDefault="qualified"> 
    <element name="Signature" type="ds:SignatureType"/>
    <complexType name="SignatureType">
        <sequence> 
            <element name="elem1" type="string"/>
            <element name="elem2" type="string"/>
        </sequence>  
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

Прочитать нужно тег element который дочерний для schema

Comment: Приведите нормальный вариант xml. Такой, чтобы его можно было скопировать и использовать в примере кода.

Comment: Добавил полный текст

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/841657/218063

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Упомянутый в вопросе `targetNamespace` используется в XmlSchema. Он не имеет никакого отношения К разбору xml.

Однако, в показанном xml наличествует пространство имён по умолчанию: `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`. Следовательно, все элементы без префикса относятся к этому неймспейсу. Для обращения к таким элементам нужно обязательно указывать это пространство имён.

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("test.xml");

var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("def", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/def:schema/def:element", nsmgr);
```

Здесь создаётся менеджер пространства имён, в который мы добавляем нужный неймспейс, назначая ему при этом префикс - в данном случае `def` (default) - можно использовать абсолютно любой.

Далее в xpath необходимо указывать этот префикс. Причём обязательно для каждого узла, который относится именно к этому пространству имён: `/def:schema/def:element`.

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало! )) Видимо, если были бы еще узлы, начинающиеся с "ds:", то чтобы к ним обращаться, в XmlNamespaceManager нужно было бы добавить строку, которая прописана в "xmlns:ds". А для чего все-таки тогда нужен атрибут targetNamespace?

Comment: @Pustota - `targetNamespace` указывает, к какому пространству имён относятся _описываемые_ в данной схеме элементы: `Signature`, `SignatureType`, `elem1`, `elem2`. | Это никак не относится к парсингу xml. Читайте про XmlSchema. | Не спрашивайте в комментариях. Создайте _новый_ вопрос.